# How do I set the default Remote Desktop (RDP) password in Azure?

Tags: azure

How do I set the default password for the Remote Desktop in an Azure Web Application?

After deploy it's set to some password I don't have, it's not my account password or admin password.

I can login if I configure a new password for the role after deploy but it's a bit annoying after 5-10 deploys.

(The default certificate is "CN=Windows Azure Tools")

UPDATE: I'm publishing via TFS (Preview)

Comment: Have you done as per: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/remote-desktop/ ? That says you can set the user name and password you want to use for Remote Desktop, and sounds like you'd only do that once

Comment: Forgot to say I'm publishing through TFS so I don't see that dialog. I updated the question.

Comment: Does that matter? "Right-click the name of your project, and then click Configure Remote Desktop" to get that dialog - the credentials get stored in the configuration definition files. Presumably, after you've done step 1, you then push into TFS and magic happens

Comment: You're right. It doesn't matter. I've must have misread the first section or something. Your solution works perfect! Add it as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consolidation of worked out solution from comments above....

Follow **Step 1** from: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/remote-desktop/. This allows you to specify the account credentials to use for Remote Desktop and they get stored in the configuraton definition files.

After that, push in to TFS and let the magic happen :)